# Где утечка памяти и есть ли она вообще?

Tags: c++, указатели, память, дерево

Изучаю структуры данных. Сделал бинарное дерево. Однако библиотека для детектирования утечек памяти говорит, что у меня происходит утечка памяти в методе add_node(), где я динамически выделяю память для узла. Но я же вроде удаляю и освобождаю память в деструкторе и в методе delete_tree()/delete_subtree()? Тогда почему утечка памяти? Или это утилита глючит?

Заранее спасибо за помощь, советы и критика приветствуются.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

#define __CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW

using namespace std;

class Tree {

private:

    struct TNode {
        int memory;
        TNode* left;
        TNode* right;
    };

    TNode* root;
    bool empty;

public:

    using Node = TNode;

    Tree() {

        this->root = new Node;
        this->root->memory = NULL;
        this->root->left = NULL;
        this->root->right = NULL;

        this->empty = true;

    }

    ~Tree() {
        if (not this->empty) {
            delete_tree();
        }
    }

    bool* is_empty() {
        return &this->empty;
    }

    Node* get_root() {
        return this->root;
    }

    void delete_subtree(Node* sub_root) {

        stack <Node*> nodes_to_delete;

        do {

            if (sub_root == NULL) {
                break;
            }

            if (sub_root->right != NULL) {
                nodes_to_delete.push(sub_root->right);
            }
            if (sub_root->left != NULL) {
                nodes_to_delete.push(sub_root->left);
            }


            delete sub_root;
            sub_root = NULL;

            if (not nodes_to_delete.empty()) {
                sub_root = nodes_to_delete.top();
                nodes_to_delete.pop();
            }

        } while (not nodes_to_delete.empty());

    }

    void delete_tree() {
        delete_subtree(this->root);
        this->root = NULL;
        this->empty = true;
    }

    void add_node(int value) {

        Node* rRoot = this->root;

        Node* node = new Node;
        node->memory = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;

        while (true) {

            if (*is_empty() == true) {
                rRoot->memory = value;
                this->empty = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (value < rRoot->memory) {
                if (rRoot->left == NULL) {
                    rRoot->left = node;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    rRoot = rRoot->left;
                }
            } 
            else if (value > rRoot->memory) {
                if (rRoot->right == NULL) {
                    rRoot->right = node;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    rRoot = rRoot->right;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    void print_tree_vertical() {

        stack <Node*> nodes_stack;
        Node* sub_root = get_root();

        while (true) {

            if (sub_root == NULL or not sub_root) {
                cout << "Нет корня!!!\n";
                break;
            }

            if (sub_root->memory == NULL) {
                cout << "Value: " << sub_root->memory << "\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Value: " << sub_root->memory << "\n";
                if (sub_root->left != NULL) {
                    cout << "Left: " << sub_root->left->memory << "\n";
                }
                if (sub_root->right != NULL) {
                    cout << "Right: " << sub_root->right->memory << "\n";
                }
                cout << "\n";
            }

            if (sub_root->right != NULL) {
                nodes_stack.push(sub_root->right);
            }
            if (sub_root->left != NULL) {
                nodes_stack.push(sub_root->left);
            }

            if (not nodes_stack.empty()) {
                sub_root = nodes_stack.top();
                nodes_stack.pop();
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

};

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    int arr[15] = {5, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

    Tree tree = Tree();
    /*tree.add_node(5);
    tree.add_node(4);
    tree.add_node(6);
    tree.add_node(1);
    tree.delete_tree();*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        tree.add_node(arr[i]);
    }

    tree.print_tree_vertical();
    cout << "-----------------------\n";
    tree.delete_tree();
    tree.print_tree_vertical();

    system("pause"); _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); return 0;

}
```

В соответствии с комментариями изменил метод таким образом, чтобы память выделялась только тогда, когда ее нужны выделить, однако, утилита все равно ругается на 115 строчку, где память выделяется. Причем именно на ту часть, где выделение идет в случае value > rRoot->memory. Хотя присвоение идет. Где-то еще закопалась ошибка? Вот новый код метода:

```
void add_node(int value) {

    Node* rRoot = this->root;

    while (true) {

        if (*is_empty() == true) {
            rRoot->memory = value;
            this->empty = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (value < rRoot->memory) {
            if (rRoot->left == NULL) {
                Node* node = new Node;
                node->memory = value;
                node->left = NULL;
                node->right = NULL;
                rRoot->left = node;
                break;
            }
            else {
                rRoot = rRoot->left;
            }
        } 
        else if (value > rRoot->memory) {
            if (rRoot->right == NULL) {
                Node* node = new Node;
                node->memory = value;
                node->left = NULL;
                node->right = NULL;
                rRoot->right = node;
                break;
            }
            else {
                rRoot = rRoot->right;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Если Вы аккуратно посмотрите, то обнаружите, что иногда в  add_node Вы создаете ноду, но никуда не присваиваете.

Comment: Ну, смотрите, в `add_node` выделили память `Node* node = new Node;`, затем в цикле `while`, если верно условие `*is_empty() == true`, вы никак не используете переменную `node` прерываете цикл с помощью `break`, выходите из функции, и тот участок памяти, на который указывал указатель `node` утекает... Это первое, что бросилось в глаза, дальше не проверял.

Comment: И действительно. Спасибо

Comment: Подправил код, но ошибка сохранилась в том же месте. Тему обновил

Comment: зря вы указатель на empty наружу выдаете, и можно просто проверять `if(*is_empty())`

Comment: да, учусь только, уже была мысль спрятать вообще все и сделать по ООП, но раньше этого столкнулся с утечкой памяти и теперь вместо улучшения кода сижу и разбираюсь, где я навтыкал

Comment: А Вам не кажется вот это присванивание странным `rRoot = rRoot->left;`Старое значение то теряется. А оно точно не nullptr.

Comment: Откройте для себя RAII

Comment: Оно и не должно удаляться. Это метод добавления ноды. rRoot = rRoot->left; двигает нас дальше влево по ветке. Если число меньше, чем значение узла и при этом есть куда двигаться.

Comment: Ну, смотрите :D в методе `delete_subtree` в цикле `do ... while` вы удаляете по одному узлу. Когда в стеке остаётся всего один узел, вы его извлекаете из стека `sub_root = nodes_to_delete.top(); nodes_to_delete.pop();`, чтобы удалить на следующей итерации, но т.к. теперь стек пуст, то условие `while (not nodes_to_delete.empty());` не выполняется, следовательно цикл прерывается, узел остаётся неудалённым, память утекает.

Comment: Да. Я сам заметил, что ошибка где-то в функции удаления. Решил сделать более адекватным способом, убрав if и перед циклом вставляя корень дерева в стек заранее. Ошибка пропала, однако, я не понял почему.

Ваш комментарий прояснил все. Спасибо большое